# How do markers, blocks, and parts work in MSC Adams?

Tags: simulation, cad, software

What are the **properties**, **purposes** and **relationships** between: **Markers**, **Blocks** and **Parts** in MSC Adams?

I don't understand how to use them properly.

Comment: Hi Harry de winton, welcome to Engineering SE. Please give an example of how you have used them, or tried to use them, and what problem you came up against. You can [edit] your question with these details.

Comment: Apologies for the poor question, but it was open ended deliberately. I am new and literature can be a little hard to come by on on the fundamentals of Adams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Markers are coordinate systems they represent a position and orientation. Parts represents separate rigid bodies and ground.

Each actionable part consists of atleast one marker which represents the center of gravity of a part.  Parts and most other modeling elemenrs act as groups to markers.

Markers represent the mathematical unerpinnings of systems, each joint (constraint) has a marker in both parts, forces emanate to and from markers, and measuremenrs are made to markers. For the simulation to work all you need are parts, markers, forces and joints.

Rest are convenience, you do not need geometry for example. For example geometry it does make easier to generate innertia values, softbody stfnesses and interpretting the result animations.